# Coding Bat>Python>String-1>extra_endの問題　要素の取り出し方が分かりません

Tags: python

#### 問題

> Given a string, return a new string made of 3 copies of the last 2 chars of the original string. The string length will be at least 2.
> extra_end('Hello') → 'lololo'
> extra_end('ab') → 'ababab'
> extra_end('Hi') → 'HiHiHi'

#### 自分の回答

```
def extra_end(str):
    return str[len(str)-2:len(str)-1]*3
```

こう回答すると、正解になりません。答えもなくて困っています。教えて欲しいです。

Comment: `str[begin:end]` は `str[begin]` から `str[end-1]` までの要素を取り出します(`str[end]` は含みません)。ちなみに、"last 2 chars" の指定は `str[-2:]` と書くこともできます。

Comment: @metropolis　回答は回答欄に書くべきではないでしょうか？